# Error converting JSONArray to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to extract and process some JSON data, but it is erroring when I try. This is my code:

```java
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String err=null;
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
        LASTNAME = user_data.getString("lastname");
        PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
        EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("lastname", LASTNAME);
    i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
    i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
    i.putExtra("err", err);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

But this is the error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value [] at user_data of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

[image: error output]

Comment: what is value of root in logcat

Comment: can u paste logcat with some log.d("rootval",root);

Comment: add your response here too? then we can help.

Comment: I have reformatted your question to make it more readable, and adjusted the title too. Further [edit]s would be welcome, if you can clarify or expand on your question some more.

Comment: **STORING UN-ENCRYPTED PASSWORDS CAN BE FATAL**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with casting Array to Object.

[..] means it is JSONArray.

{..} means it is JSONObject.

```
try {
    JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    //This is how you get value from 1 element in JSONArray
    String firstObjectValue = jObj.getString(0);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

If you looking for value need you to iterate all JSONArray
 by doing some simple loop.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
     try {
         jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
         JSONArray jsonARRAY = jsonObject.getJSONArray("nameOfJSONArray");
         for (int i = 0; i < jsonARRAY.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject jsonOBJECT = (JSONObject) jsonARRAY.get(i);
             String yourValue = jsonOBJECT.getString("valueKey");

         }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your "user_data" is coming as json array instead of json object that you are trying to access.

you can use `root.optJSONObject("user_data")` to determine & return json object if your user_data is json object or will return null.

Comment: How i can do it
root.optJSONObject("user_data") is not working